# How Can I Get a full scholarship to a University by my Skills | as an International Student?

Tags: application, united-states, funding, computer-science, international-students

I'm a student in my last year of high school, I'm from Europe but I'm looking for studying Computer Science in USA for the next year. My grades aren't great (around B/B+) and my family can't afford paying the tuition fees (neither it seems they are going help to find a solution) so I need to find a way of getting a full scolarship.

Parallel to my studies, I have been doing my own research on the area of AI for the last two years and I think I have reached a level in which I feel comfortable reading papers and coding by my own. I thought maybe I can use this to get the attention of some professors that can recommend me for the admision process.

I don't know anyone in this situation or that has done something similar so I'm kind of lost (I don't even know about anyone who has studied in USA). I think I could email some to some professors with doubts and questions about their work and start a conversation from there. But I can't think of a way of asking them for their help without looking like a beggar. How would you do this?
I know that maybe the proffesor not even has the chance to admite me nor doing anything about, this is just an idea I had and I don't know if there are other things I can do in this situation.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated, I'm decided to find a way of making this work and study in the USA.

Comment: Have you ever made contributions to GitHub? You say "_I have reached a level in which I feel comfortable reading papers and coding by my own_". You need to convince people that you did.

Comment: Yes, I have also started a couple of projects that I think have potential of become solid companies, for sure I can convince people of what I have done, but what I'm not sure about is if this is enough to get the attention of an University nor how to do it.

Comment: Why does it have to be the US and not e.g. Oxbridge or ETHZ? Those are as prestigious as good US universities, have more rigorous undergrad programs and are probably easier to get into and more affordable on top.

Comment: International students in the US often pay for their degrees with loans.  If you successfully study CS, you will very likely be able to repay the loans.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have some misunderstandings about undergraduate education in the US. A bachelors here provides a general education along with a specialization. The general courses are about 40% or more of the total.

For example the [CS program at UIUC](https://cs.illinois.edu/academics/undergraduate/degree-program-options/bs-computer-science) seems pretty typical to me. Note the wide variety of courses, including the humanities. UIUC is a highly ranked research university.

Also, undergraduate admission is generally not controlled by individuals, but by committees who may only get involved in non-obvious cases.

The situation of scholarships, especially for people who don't stand out academically, is probably even harder. And especially for an international student who can't claim historical discrimination by race or ethnicity as can some citizens here. But in particular, contacting an individual professor for this is probably going to be fruitless.

To get accepted you need letters of recommendation from your current teachers, as well as an "acceptable" academic profile. The letters need to be from people who know you well and can speak highly of you.

Some people can arrange funding from their home country or some institution there.

My guess is that you can probably get admitted to a good US program, but funding will be much harder - especially "full ride" funding. Some discounts might be available to you, as they are to many. But much of Europe has much better funding for higher education.